# Impersonation in ASP.NET Failing

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I am attempting to do seems very simple in principal. There is a directory which contains documents that I need to provide to my users however the account under which IIS is running does not have access. So what I am attempting to do is use impersonation to open the document in a .ashx with an account that does have access and write the document to the response stream.
Unfortunately unless I am hosting the website in an instance of Visual Studio which I am running as an administrator the code snippet below fails on `using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\test3.pdf", FileMode.Open))` with *System.UnauthorizedAccessException*.  This doesnt seem to make sense as impersonation seems to have taken affect as `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` returns the name of my test account and the test account does have access to open the document.  It seems like I am missing something very simple here does anyone know what it is?  I appreciate any help!!!!

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="PDFHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

public class PDFHandler : IHttpHandler {

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(
            String lpszUsername,
            String lpszDomain,
            String lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            ref IntPtr phToken);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool RevertToSelf();


    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ClearContent();
        context.Response.ClearHeaders();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        byte[] result = null;

        IntPtr admin_token = default(IntPtr);
        WindowsIdentity wid_current = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsIdentity wid_admin = null;
        WindowsImpersonationContext wic = null;

        RevertToSelf();

        if (LogonUser("test account", "Odysseus", "test", 2, 0, ref admin_token) == true)
        {
            wid_admin = new WindowsIdentity(admin_token);
            wic = wid_admin.Impersonate();
        using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\test3.pdf", FileMode.Open))
        {
            result = ReadFully(fileStream);

            fileStream.Close();
        }
        }
        else
        {
            //login failed
        }

        context.Response.BinaryWrite(result);
        context.Response.Flush();
    }

    public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] returnValue;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            returnValue = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you change the permissions on the folder?

Comment: Mike I appreciate the suggestion but unforunately I cannot the security on the folder is outside of my control.  I need to find a way to use the username and password I was provided with to do it.  Seems straight forward but has proven a little difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could move this page to a new folder and add a web.config file. Then use the [identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tag to enable impersonation. Read the remarks on how to encrypt the username and password to the registry.

Read the 'Alternatives' section on this [article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/Feb/24/Using-programmatic-Impersonation-from-an-ASPNET-Page).

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion Panos the web.config alternative may be the direction that I end up heading but I am still frustrated that I am not able to perform impersonation programatically.  It seems so simple and clean but just wont work.

Comment: The more I think about this very good suggestion I see the likely hood of getting push back from other developers on my team about the addition of another web.config.  So if anyone has any other suggestions I look forward to hearing them.

Comment: @SomeBody On the other hand, you will not have to alter your code. The impersonation is detached from the code. IMHO the best solution would be to avoid impersonation altogether. Impersonation is more suitable to workflow scenarios. Also it could become a security vulnerability. Cant't you ask whoever is responsible for the security of the folder to give read access to your application's user?

Comment: That would sure make things easier wouldnt it?  They are adamant this is how they want it to work so unfortunately giving my entire web application access isn't a possibility.  Only the user I have been provided with can have access and the access should only be available on this page.

Comment: ok I must be missing something really simple here because the web.config method is not working either.  Anyone have any additional suggestions?