# Open File as Authenticated User

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-io, iis-7.5, file-permissions

How can I open a file (`System.IO.FileStream`) as the user running the browser (`User.Identity.Name`) rather than the local network account on the server?

Request: If applicable, edit post with proper terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Impersonation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444334/impersonation-in-asp-net-failing) is a question about it.
And [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1835569.aspx/1?Impersonation+not+working+on+IIS+7+) is another thread about it.

Google can probably help alot as well, now that you know what too look for.